# Optimize Query on mysql

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, mariadb

I have a query that runs really slow (15 20 seconds) when is not on memory and quite fast when is on memory (2s - 0.6s)

```
select count(distinct(concat(conexiones.tMacAdres,date_format(conexiones.fFecha,'%Y%m%d')))) as Conexiones,
                    sum(if(conexiones.tEvento='megusta',1,0)) as MeGusta,sum(if(conexiones.tEvento='megusta',conexiones.nAmigos,0)) as ImpactosMeGusta,
                    sum(if(conexiones.tEvento='checkin',1,0)) as CheckIn,sum(if(conexiones.tEvento='checkin',conexiones.nAmigos,0)) as ImpactosCheckIn,
                    min(conexiones.fFecha) Fecha_Inicio, now() Fecha_fin,datediff(now(),min(conexiones.fFecha)) as dias
                    from conexiones, instalaciones
                    where  conexiones.idInstalacion=instalaciones.idInstalacion and conexiones.idInstalacion=190
                        and (fFecha between '2014-01-01 00:00:00' and '2016-06-18 23:59:59')
                    group by instalaciones.tNombre
                    order by instalaciones.idCliente
```

This is Table SCHEMAS:
Instalaciones with 1332 rows:

```
CREATE TABLE `instalaciones` (
  `idInstalacion` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idCliente` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `tRouterSerial` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tFacebookPage` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tidFacebook` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tNombre` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tMensaje` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tWebPage` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tDireccion` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tPoblacion` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tProvincia` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tCodigoPosta` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tLatitud` decimal(15,12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tLongitud` decimal(15,12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tSSID1` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tSSID2` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tSSID2_Pass` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fSincro` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `tEstado` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tHotspot` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fAlta` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idInstalacion`),
  UNIQUE KEY `tRouterSerial` (`tRouterSerial`),
  KEY `idInstalacion` (`idInstalacion`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1332 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Conexiones with 2370365 rows

```
CREATE TABLE `conexiones` (
  `idConexion` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idInstalacion` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `idUsuario` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tMacAdres` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tUsuario` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tNombre` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tApellido` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tEmail` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tSexo` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fNacimiento` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `nAmigos` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tPoblacion` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fFecha` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `tEvento` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idConexion`),
  KEY `idInstalacion` (`idInstalacion`),
  KEY `tMacAdress` (`tMacAdres`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `fFecha` (`fFecha`),
  KEY `idUsuario` (`idUsuario`),
  KEY `insta_fecha` (`idInstalacion`,`fFecha`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2370365 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

This is EXPLAIN

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  instalaciones   const   PRIMARY,idInstalacion   PRIMARY 4   const   1   
1   SIMPLE  conexiones  ref idInstalacion,fFecha,insta_fecha    idInstalacion   5   const   110234  "Using where"
```

Thanks !

(Edited)

SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'conexiones'

```
  Name  Engine  Version Row_format  Rows    Avg_row_length  Data_length Max_data_length Index_length    Data_free   Auto_increment  Create_time Update_time Check_time  Collation   Checksum    Create_options  Comment
 conexiones InnoDB  10  Compact 2305296 151 350060544   0   331661312   75497472    2433305 28/06/2016 22:26    NULL    NULL    utf8_general_ci NULL
```

Comment: Delete the `idInstalacion` INDEX - you don't need it. You allready have KEY `insta_fecha` (`idInstalacion`,`fFecha`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's *why* it is so slow.  And I will end with a *possible* speedup.

First, please do

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM conexiones
    WHERE idInstalacion=190
      and fFecha >= '2014-01-01'
      and fFecha  < '2016-06-19
```

in order to see how many rows we are dealing with.  The EXPLAIN suggests 110234, but that is only a crude estimate.

Assuming there are 110K rows of `conexiones` involved in the query, and assuming the rows were (approximately) inserted in chronological order by `fFecha`, then...

- There are a lot of rows to work with, and
- They are scattered around the table on disk, hence
- The query takes a lot of I/O, unless it is cached.

Let's further check on my last claim...  How much RAM do you have?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  It should be about 70% of *available* RAM.  *Use a lower percentage if you have less than 4GB of RAM.*

Assuming that `conexiones` is too big to be 'cached' in the 'buffer_pool', we need to find a way to decrease the I/O.

There are 1332 different values for `idInstalacion`.  Perhaps you insert 1332 rows every few minutes/hours into `conexiones`?  Since the `PRIMARY KEY` merely an `AUTO_INCREMENT`, those rows will be 'appended' to the end of the table.

Now let's look at where the `idInstalacion=190` rows are.  A new one of them occurs every 1332 (or so) rows.  That means they are spread out.  It means that (probably) no two rows are in the same block (16KB in InnoDB).  That means that the 110234 will be in 110234 different blocks.  That's about 2GB.  If the buffer_pool is smaller than that, then there *will* be I/O.  Even if it is bigger than that, that's a lot of data to touch.

But what to do about it?  If we could arrange the `=190` rows to be consecutive in the table, then the 2GB might drop to, say, 20MB -- a much more manageable and cacheable size.  But how can that be done?  By changing the `PRIMARY KEY`.

```
PRIMARY KEY(idInstalacion, fFecha, idConexion),
INDEX(idConexion)
```

and `DROP` any other indexes starting with `idInstalacion` or `idConexion`.  To explain:

- Since the PK is "clustered" with the data, all `idInstalacion=190` rows over any consecutive `fFetcha` range will be consecutive in the data.  So, fetching one block will get about 100 rows -- much less I/O.
- A PK *must* be unique.  Assuming `(idInstalacion, fFecha)` is not unique, I tacked on `idConexion` to make it unique.
- I added `INDEX(idConexion)` to make `AUTO_INCREMENT` happy.

Potential drawback...  Since this change rearranges the order of the data, other queries, including the `INSERTs` *may* be slowed down.  The `INSERTs` will be scattered, but not really slowed down.  1332 "hots spots" would be accepting the new rows; that many blocks can easily be cached.

Arithmetic...  If you have spinning drives, I would expect the existing structure to take about 1102 seconds (perhaps under 110 seconds for SSD) for 110234 rows.  Since it is taking under 20 seconds, I suspect there is some caching (or you have SSDs) or the 110234 is grossly overestimated.  My suggested change should decrease the "worst" time significantly, and slightly improve the "in memory" time.  This "slight improvement" comes from being able to use the PK instead of a secondary key.

Caveat:  Since 110234 * 1332 is nowhere near 2370365, much of my numerical analysis is probably nowhere near correct.  For example, 2370365 rows with that schema is possible less than 1GB.  Please provide `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'conexiones'`.

**Addenda**

"server has 2GB Ram and innodb_buffer_pool_size is 5368709120" -- Either that is a typo or it is *terrible*.  Since the buffer_pool needs to reside in RAM, do not set the buffer_pool to 5GB.  500MB might be OK for your tiny 2GB of RAM.

The `SHOW TABLE STATUS` confirms that it (data + indexes) won't quite fit in 500M, so you may periodically experience I/O bound queries with 500M.

Increasing your RAM and buffer_pool would temporarily (until the data gets bigger) help performance.

Before putting this into production, test the `ALTER` and time the various queries you use:

```
ALTER TABLE conexiones
    DROP PRIMARY KEY,
    DROP INDEX insta_fecha,
    DROP INDEX idInstalacion,
    PRIMARY KEY(idInstalacion, fFecha, idConexion),
    INDEX(idConexion)
```

Caution:  The `ALTER` will need about 1GB of free disk space.

When timing, run with the Query Cache off, and run twice -- the first may involve I/O; the second is the 'in memory' as you mentioned.

Revised analysis:  Since the bigger table has 300MB of data and some amount of indexes in use, and assuming 500MB buffer pool, I suspect that blocks are bumped out of the buffer pool some of the time.  This fits well with your initial comment on the query's speed.  My suggested index changes *should* help avoid the speed variance, but *may* hurt the performance of other queries.

Comment: Hi Rick, sorry for the delay. Abount coun(*) of your first question: 59317, as you told i'm using SSD disk. The server has 2GB Ram and innodb_buffer_pool_size is 5368709120. Show Tables updated on main question. How i should do alter table in order to modify the index ?

Comment: See Addenda in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a multi column index:

```
CREATE idx_nn_1 ON conexiones(idInstalacion,fFecha);
```

You might need to have it the other way around depending on the data, so test both. This avoids reading all the records for between condition on `fFecha` matching the `idInstalacion` condition, and should improve performance.

Comment: It is allready created KEY `insta_fecha` (`idInstalacion`,`fFecha`) even forcing to use that index isn't faster. Do you mean by other way to create:  CREATE fecha_insta ON conexiones(fFecha,idInstalacion); ? Do I need to delete first the other one ?

Comment: Sorry, did not see that key. Try the other way around as in your comment and see what happens (indexing is analysis combined with some trial and error)

Comment: Same results .. even on explain still not using index fecha_insta nor insta_fecha, still using idInstalacion index.

Comment: Ok, this should be the same, but still give it a try: Replace `                    from conexiones, instalaciones
                    where  conexiones.idInstalacion=instalaciones.idInstalacion and conexiones.idInstalacion=190
                        and (fFecha between '2014-01-01 00:00:00' and '2016-06-18 23:59:59')
`

with `from conexiones INNER JOIN instalaciones ON conexiones.idInstalacion=instalaciones.idInstalacion and conexiones.idInstalacion=190
                        and (fFecha between '2014-01-01 00:00:00' and '2016-06-18 23:59:59')`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

Either delete the `idInstalacion` INDEX or tell the engine to use the correct key in the from clause:

```sql
from conexiones use index (insta_fecha), instalaciones
```

And you don't need to JOIN, GROUP or ORDER. You are joining on a constant value (190) with one row. And you don't use any column from `instalaciones`.

So all you need is this:

```sql
select count(distinct(concat(conexiones.tMacAdres,date_format(conexiones.fFecha,'%Y%m%d')))) as Conexiones,
    sum(if(conexiones.tEvento='megusta',1,0)) as MeGusta,sum(if(conexiones.tEvento='megusta',conexiones.nAmigos,0)) as ImpactosMeGusta,
    sum(if(conexiones.tEvento='checkin',1,0)) as CheckIn,sum(if(conexiones.tEvento='checkin',conexiones.nAmigos,0)) as ImpactosCheckIn,
    min(conexiones.fFecha) Fecha_Inicio, now() Fecha_fin,datediff(now(),min(conexiones.fFecha)) as dias
    from conexiones -- use index (insta_fecha)
    where conexiones.idInstalacion=190
    and (fFecha between '2014-01-01 00:00:00' and '2016-06-18 23:59:59')
```

However - it doesn't mean it will be faster. MySQL will probably optimize all that stuff away.